# Working with Geolocation and Google Maps API [HELP]

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, geolocation, maps

I'm new to the mobile development world and right now I'm building an app that uses jQuery mobile and PhoneGap. Here's my logic:

- I have a table that contains the users and their addresses. I grab the user address and pass it trough the maps API to catch the location. But I'm doing this for every single record and sometimes the API breaks because the number of simultaneous requests.

How can I know what users are closest to me without running it through the maps API?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rafael, Google limits the number of requests you can do because it's against their TOS to do batch geocoding without paying for a (rather pricey) business license. You'll need to find a service that allows you to geocode addresses *en masse*.

I would recommend one like [LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) which will not only geocode the addresses but also confirm the validity and fill out missing or incorrect information. Each request to the API may include up to 100 addresses. There's a non-API version if you just want to verify an existing list of addresses in a spreadsheet or CSV file.

I do work at [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) and would be happy to help you with any other questions about your addresses.

Comment: So, I'll need to change my code to this LiveAddress right? And the fix for massive requests is export all my database addresses to a CSV file and send to this API?

Comment: Yeah, basically. I was just pointing out the reason and one possible solution; but there are other ways. LiveAddress is one suggestion; there are other APIs which may or may not fit your needs better depending on pricing, etc. You could geocode all your existing addresses with the API (up to 100 at a time) or export the list as, say, a CSV file, and process it all at once. But before adding new addresses to your database you'd want to geocode them and save those results along with the verified address.

Comment: I didn't get it yet, sorry. I need a service that can handle massive requests because I'm working with geolocation, I get my devices location and compare with the records location and order by the closest one. And on another pages I need to show a Map with pins for the locations. Can I do this with your service? If I can, can we talk by e-mail and see the prices?

Comment: Yes; use the device's built-in geolocation features to find its coordinates, and you can use a geocoding service (like LiveAddress, etc.) to get the coordinates for the addresses in your table, against which you can compare the device's coordinates. You can send an email to us, found on the [contact page](http://smartystreets.com/contact). [Prices are on our website](http://smartystreets.com/pricing).