# Google Maps API Requests Performance Issues

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a App that uses geolocation via google maps api ( Distance Matrix and Maps API ) to calculate the distance and show pins on the map. I'm having performance issues with my logic ( I have 100 addresses at my database, I grab them all, I run all into the distance matrix and get the distance for my location) I'm doing this every single time the user clicks on the update location button. But there's a catch with that method, I'm making 100 requests every time the refresh button is clicked and it is just for 1 user. Obviously sometimes the API richs the limit of requests per day. My question is: How can I get better performance and improve my logic for this App to run faster and doesn't reach the daily request limit? I have about 1000 people using this app.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Open the connection with the database
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'gennovacap', 'coupons');
mysql_select_db('coupons', $conn);

$id_voucher = $_POST['id_voucher'];
$uuid = $_POST['uuid'];
// $uuid = "1343C38F-C0F3-4D86-B763-C14CFBF1DAC3";
// $id_voucher = 8;


$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE id_voucher = ".$id_voucher);
$voucher = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

if(preg_match('/[\+]{2}+/', $voucher['address'])) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach(explode('++', $voucher['address']) as $address){

        $address = preg_replace('/\s/m', '+', $address);
        $request = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address."&sensor=true";
        $result = simplexml_load_file($request);

        $latitude = $result->result->geometry->location[0]->lat;
        $longitude = $result->result->geometry->location[0]->lng;

        $json['markers'][$i]['latitude'] = $latitude;
        $json['markers'][$i]['longitude'] = $longitude;
        $json['markers'][$i]['titlev'] = $voucher['name'];

        $i++;
    }

} else {
    
    $address = preg_replace('/\s/m', '+', $voucher['address']);
    $request = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address."&sensor=true";
    $result = simplexml_load_file($request);

    $latitude = $result->result->geometry->location[0]->lat;
    $longitude = $result->result->geometry->location[0]->lng;

    $json['markers'][0]['latitude'] = $latitude[0];
    $json['markers'][0]['longitude'] = $longitude[0];
    $json['markers'][0]['titlev'] = $voucher['name'];

}

// See if the user redeemed this coupon
$redemption = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM redemptions WHERE uuid = '".$uuid."' AND id_voucher = '".$id_voucher."'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($redemption);
if($count > 0) {
    $created_at = mysql_fetch_row($redemption);
    $json['titlev'] = $voucher['name'];
    $json['deal'] = $voucher['deal'];
    $json['redemptions'] = false;
    $json['redemptions_text'] = $created_at[3];
} else {
    $json['titlev'] = $voucher['name'];
    $json['deal'] = $voucher['deal'];
    $json['redemptions'] = true;
    $json['redemptions_text'] = "Redeem This Coupon";
}

print json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use caching to reduce the number of requests?

Also something I've done in the past is that when I hit the limit on google API requests and fallback to another service like Yahoo or something.

I'm not sure if Yahoo has the same functionality but it might be worth looking into

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [Rafael Fragoso's question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505555/working-with-geolocation-and-google-maps-api-help) and my answer there applies here. As Andrew said, you can cache it temporarily (so an address geocoded by one user can be stored *temporarily* -- that's important for conforming to TOS) for other users needing that address in the next hour or several minutes or whatever.

A much better, more robust solution, however, is to find an API that lifts the query limits and is more perpetual. See my linked answer for a suggestion to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you are looking up the lat/lng repeatedly. It would be much easier to add a map lookup to the interface you use to add/edit addresses and store the lat/lng directly in your database. When you edit an address, do so through a web browser displaying a Google map and use JavaScript to push the lat/lng into hidden fields that then get posted back to a server side script that can put them in the database.

Then when you need the pin data you can pull it directly from the db. Your code will run much quicker and you will only need to touch the API 100 times total for 100 addresses rather than 100 times per usage.

Running the script client-side in JavaScript, you will not hit a limit, except possibly the 10/second throughput limit if you run these in a batch, but that will not apply if you do them one at a time.